# Converting data from wcf using reflection Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, json, wcf, reflection, int

I'm retrieving a datatable from a wcf function WebMessageFormat = Json and then setting the properties of my data contract using reflection. I'm getting the following error on an int field -

> Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32

Can somebody explain what this is and how to address?

Comment: Sure... You cannot fit 64 bit integer into 32 bit integer number. There's not enough space to express the value. The maximum value of Int64 is  9,223,372,036,854,775,807 whereas the maximum for Int32 is much smaller - 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When casting boxed value-type values, you must cast to the correct type. For example:

```
var myLong = (object)42L;

var intValue = (int)myLong; // WRONG - myLong is a boxed long, not int
var intValue2 = (int)(long)myLong; // CORRECT - myLong is unboxed first, then converted
```

Note that you may get an `OverflowException` if `int` isn't big enough to contain your `long` value even when you unbox the value correctly.

Comment: Does this mean that unlike all other fields, if the field is an int, I always need to convert from long first? So for all fields, I can just var value = row.Field<object>(property.Name);
                        property.SetValue(contract, value != DBNull.Value ? value : null, null); but now I need to first check field type? Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @MikeTurner If the field is a value-type, you need to always cast to the exact same type, one of the interfaces it implements or `object` (not 100% true, but close enough for most purposes). It doesn't matter whether it's `int` or `DBNull`, but both sides must be the same type - there's no difference between casting a boxed `int` to `long` and doing the same with e.g. `DBNull`. `dynamic` allows you to avoid the explicit type-check (`(int)(dynamic)(object)value` will work if `(int)value` does), but may have other consequences - make sure you understand how `dynamic` works if you go that route.

Comment: What's strange is that I've returned ints before and have never ran into this problem, is there a way I can get my wcf function to return int32 instead of int64? I'm confused as to why this suddenly popped up now when I added an int field to my function?

Comment: @MikeTurner You're not showing enough of your code to answer that. Note that JSON doesn't have `int` (or `long`, for that matter) - all JSON numbers are something more like C#'s `decimal`.

Comment: so maybe it's my stored procedure in sql - I can successfully return 1 as ID and convert that to int32 without any modifications, however, when I return an int field of a custom type table (create type as table (id int)) that is causing the error

Comment: I tried converting to smallint but that didn't work. any ideas?

Comment: actually, I figured it out. thanks for your help! was a windows function returning the non int32 value...